# Android ROOM: How to return an aliased column that is not persisted

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

**OBJECTIVE**

Be able to return calculated and aliased columns without persisting them

**WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED**

Using this snippet below, I want to get `studentCount` without ever having to create its corresponding column:

```sql
SELECT i.*, (
        SELECT COUNT(s.id) 
        FROM students s 
        WHERE s.instructorId = i.id
    ) AS studentCount 
FROM instructors i
```

My POJO models look like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Student {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private long instructorId;

    public long getId(){ return id; }
    public long getInstructorId(){ return instructorId; }
    public String getFirstName(){ return firstName; }
    public String getLastName(){ return lastName; }

    public void setId(long id){ this.id = id; }
    public void setInstructorId(long id){ this.instructorId = id; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstname){ this.firstName = firstName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastname){ this.lastname = lastname; }
}

public class NestingClass {
    public int studentCount;
}

@Entity
public class Instructor {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String fullNname;

    @Embedded
    private NestingClass studentCount; // Do not persist

    public long getId(){ return id; }
    public String getFullName(){ return fullName; }
    public Nestingclass getStudentCount(){ return studentCount; }

    public void setId(long id){ this.id = id; }
    public void setFullName(String fullName){ this.fullName = fullName; }
    public void setStudentCount(NestingClass sc){ this.studentCount = sc; }
}
```

**CURRENT BEHAVIOR**

The query works but a corresponding column for `studentCount` is created in the resulting database which is the opposite of what I'd like to have.

Also, if I remove the `@Embedded` annotation, and use `@Ignore`, I get an error about missing column.

If I change the type of the dynamic column to its native type, I get an error about the field not being able to be converted to an entity.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

Same as objective

---

So, how can I execute the above query without Room creating a column?

Comment: Have you tried removing `AS studentCount` and returning the value as an `int` directly in your DAO? For example `@Query("...SQL above") public int getStudentCount(...);`.

Comment: @Sandi No, because I want it to be returned along with the other columns as one entity so I do not have to query the database again when the results are passed to the ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are going about this in reverse to what you should be doing.

Consider the following where

**NestingClass.java** is :-

```
public class NestingClass {
    public int studentCount;
    @Embedded
    Instructor instructor;

    public NestingClass(StudentInstructorDao studentInstructorDao, int instructorId) {
        this.instructor = studentInstructorDao.getInstructor(instructorId);
        this.studentCount = studentInstructorDao.getStudentCount(instructorId);
    }

    public Instructor getInstructor() {
        return instructor;
    }

    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }

    public int getStudentCount() {
        return studentCount;
    }

    public void setStudentCount(int studentCount) {
        this.studentCount = studentCount;
    }
}
```

- i.e. the Instructor has been embedded.

and **Instructor.class** is :-

```
@Entity
public class Instructor {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String fullNname;

    public long getId(){ return id; }
    public String getFullNname() { return fullNname; }
    public void setId(long id){ this.id = id; }
    public void setFullNname(String fullName){ this.fullNname = fullName; }
}
```

- i.e. The student count is not part of the Instructor

And the Dao **StudentInstructorDao.java** is :-

```
@Dao
public interface StudentInstructorDao {

    @Insert
    long insertStudent(Student student);

    @Insert
    long[] insertStudents(Student... students);

    @Insert
    long insertInstructor(Instructor instructor);

    @Insert
    long[] insertInstructors(Instructor... instructors);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Instructor WHERE id = :instructorId")
    Instructor getInstructor(long instructorId);

    @Query("SELECT count() FROM Instructor JOIN student ON student.instructorId = Instructor.id WHERE Instructor.id = :instructorId" )
    int getStudentCount(long instructorId);
}
```

The the following testing code :-

```
    mStudentInstructorDao = mDatabase.studentInstructorDao();
    Instructor i1 = new Instructor();
    i1.setFullNname("I1");
    Instructor i2 = new Instructor();
    i2.setFullNname("I2");
    mStudentInstructorDao.insertInstructors(i1,i2);
    Student s1 = new Student();
    s1.setFirstName("S1");
    s1.setLastName("LS1");
    s1.setInstructorId(1);
    Student s2 = new Student();
    s2.setFirstName("S1");
    s2.setInstructorId(1);
    s2.setLastName("LS2");
    mStudentInstructorDao.insertStudents(s1,s2);
    NestingClass nc = new NestingClass(mStudentInstructorDao,1);
    Log.d("INSTRUCTORINFO","Instructor " + nc.getInstructor().getFullNname() + " has " + nc.getStudentCount() + " Students");
```

Results, when run, in the log containing :-

```
2019-10-16 09:05:53.472 D/INSTRUCTORINFO: Instructor I1 has 2 Students
```

## Alternative

An alternative approach could be to do away with NestingClass and have **Instructor.class** as

```
@Entity
public class Instructor {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String fullNname;

    public long getId(){ return id; }
    public String getFullNname() { return fullNname; }
    public void setId(long id){ this.id = id; }
    public void setFullNname(String fullName){ this.fullNname = fullName; }
    //<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>
    public int getStudentCount(StudentInstructorDao studentInstructorDao) {
        return studentInstructorDao.getStudentCount(this.id);
    }
}
```

The using :-

```
    Instructor i = mStudentInstructorDao.getInstructor(1);
    Log.d("STUDENTCOUNT","Instructor " + i.getFullNname() + " has " + i.getStudentCount(mStudentInstructorDao) + " Students");
```

results in (for the same data) :-

```
2019-10-16 09:33:39.582 D/STUDENTCOUNT: Instructor I1 has 2 Students
```